# Use a cursor in a service or send data via a bind to the service

Tags: android, service, binding, cursor

I have an Sqlite database that has a collection of locations. A content provider is used to access this database.

The locations will then be flagged as active or not in the database by clicking on the list of locations in an activty.

A service then runs that will listen to the active locations and do something when the location is reached.

My question is what would be the best way for the service to operate.

Either have it monitor a cursor of the active locations that gets automatically updated on a change of the data. All the activity with the list of the locations would have to do is set the location as active and then call the service intent to make sure its running.

The advantage of this, as I see it, is that whatever happens in the database the service is upto date. But I'm not sure whether keeping an open cursor and traversing it every time there is a location change is efficient.

The other way would be to have the activity set the location as active in the database and then bind to the service and send it the location data to listen to. The service then stores this in a listarray, and whenever there is location change traverse the list to see if the location has been reached.

Disadvantage of this is that for each location amendment the service would have to be bound to and the location changed. An advantage could be that no cursor is open and only a small listarray with the location in is stored.

So either cursor in a service or binding to the service? Or is there an even better way that I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

It's a balance of efficiency versus code complexity.

I would register an observer on the provider and then update my list of active locations every time the provider is modified, then I'd scan the list against the current location. The observer doesn't need to be associated with a Cursor, although you will have to requery the provider when the ContentObserver.onChange() is called.

Remember to do this work in the *background*. Use an IntentService or write your own Service that runs a HandlerThread; I prefer using a IntentService or Service because they're not affected by Activity lifecycle events in the same way that AsyncTask is.

Comment: We can use Volley in Service? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18043860/volley-or-service-with-cursor-loader